# What is the meaning of "enhanced" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

"She was a very kind and caring person, and the team was enhanced by her presence"?
I guess it means that her presence contributed to the positive atmosphere in the team. Is that correct?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I like the resource OneLook.com for looking up the definition of a word in a dictionary. Why don't you try it for *enhanced*, and tell us what you find? What does the dictionary say the word means? Which definitions does it give that seem relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes..! The team might already be very good but her presence brings in a renewed sense of strength and stature into the team also adds up to the positive atmosphere.
Also it can be seen as the team being more effective to do a task with her being present around.

Comment: @Marina You are most welcome! May I know why has this been down voted?

Comment: Dear Rohit, I did not down-vote you - quite the opposite! But when I try to click on "this answer is useful", I get a message that my reputation is not enough "to change the publicly displayed post score". I'm very sorry that I can't do anything about it! Maybe someone else down voted your answer? I'm really sorry!

Comment: It is alright Marina! I know it wasn't you so it is fine :)